# NULL Values Keep Terminating My NSString

Tags: objective-c, char, hex, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a line of hex to a line of char values. This is the code I use:

```
// Store HEX values in a mutable string:
    NSUInteger capacity = [data length] * 2;
    NSMutableString *stringBuffer = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:capacity];
    const unsigned char *dataBuffer = [data bytes];
    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i<[data length]; ++i) {
        [stringBuffer appendFormat:@"%02X ", (NSUInteger)dataBuffer[i]];
    }
// Log it:
  NSLog(@"stringBuffer is %@",stringBuffer);


// Convert string from HEX to char values:
NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:content];
unsigned value;
while([scanner scanHexInt:&value]) {
    [newString appendFormat:@"%c ",(char)(value & 0xFF)];
}
NSLog(@"newString is %@", newString);
```

This works great, so far. The output received it as expected:

```
String Buffer is 3D 3E 2C 01 2C 31 33 30 37 31 38 30 39 32 34 2D 30 37 2C FF 00 00 00 00 00
 newString is = > ,  , 1 3 0 7 1 8 0 9 2 4 - 0 7 , ˇ
```

There is just one problem, the NULL values are terminating my string (I think). New string should type "0 0 0 0", but it doesn't, it just ends there. I think it is ending there because 3 zeros in a row = NULL in char. Does anyone know how I can prevent this string from terminating and display the entire value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%c` format does not produce any output for the NULL character, but is does also
not terminate the string. See the following example:

```
NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[newString appendFormat:@"%c", 0x30]; // the '0' character
[newString appendFormat:@"%c", 0x00]; // the NULL character
[newString appendFormat:@"%c", 0x31]; // the '1' character
NSLog(@"newString is %@", newString);
// Output: newString is 01
NSLog(@"length is %ld", newString.length);
// Output: length is 2
```

So you can not expect to get any output for the hex input `00`. In particular, you can not
expect to get the character "0" because that has the ASCII code hex `30`, not `00`.

Note that you can convert `NSData` to `NSString` directly using

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];
```

if `data` represents a string in some encoding, e.g. UTF-8 (which is not the case with
your data).

A better answer might be possible if you explain what the data represents and what
string representation of the data you want.

Comment: I see. As I checked the output, the string wasn't terminated. The 00's were represented by blank spaces. You're the man Martin, thank you.